# How does this code to move the app to the background work?

Tags: android

I wanted a way to exit my app. Hence I searched and found a piece of code which does that.
But I am not able to understand the code and why it does what it does.
Can anyone please explain?

Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Where did you find this code ? As far as I searched, it does not sound very efficient / widely used.

Comment: Wrong search. This code doesn't finish your app. It opens an Activity. By the way, close your app by simply going back to the home screen. Let Android take care of killing the background processes as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's starting the action `ACTION_MAIN` that has the category `CATEGORY_HOME`. This [corresponds to](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_HOME):

> This is the home activity, that is the first activity that is displayed when the device boots.

So, this means the launcher. So, this is a fancy way of starting the launcher app.

Also, the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` means it will be started on a new task, not the same as your app is running.

Notice that **this will not finish your app**, it will just put it in the background (like switching to another app using the task switcher, just this app happens to be the launcher). The effect is **the same as pressing the home button**.

Also notice that if the user happens to have two launcher apps, and it has not selected the default one, it will get a chooser asking to select which one of the two (or more) apps wants to use. Not the best experience.